# Is there a way to slightly adjust the subtitles offset in the VLC player?

Tags: applications, vlc

Is there a way to slightly adjust the subtitles offset in the VLC player?

Often I just need they to appear 1 second before or later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keys <kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>j</kbd> should respectively decrease and increase the delay.

Comment: that's a lowercase h and j, not shift-h and shift-j

Comment: @msutherl Fair enough, though on most keyboards they are actually labeled in uppercase :)

Comment: true, just took me 15 minutes to figure out why it wasn't working and wanted to save anybody else the trouble – looking up Vim shortcuts has gotten me accustomed to people being rigorous about how they indicate key presses